# Google Remote Desktop: copy paste not working

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop, clipboard, chrome-remote-desktop

I use Google Remote Desktop using the Chrome web application to connect to a remote server.

Problem: I am unable to copy and paste host to remote server. How to enable it?

Comment: See https://www.anyviewer.com/how-to/chrome-remote-desktop-copy-paste-2578.html for a nice instruction

Answer (score 20):

Screenshots illustrating [sunil shakya](https://superuser.com/users/879825/sunil-shakya)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1444737/116475):

Step 1: [Open Keyboard Controls menu on Google Remote Desktop](https://superuser.com/a/1543228/116475)

Step 2: Enable clipboard synchronization:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is totally broken for me. The option is no longer available even though it was working fine yesterday, last week, and earlier today.

Comment: please upvote question & answers. I've forgotten this once already .. back for a second bite of the cherry. works on windows 10 to mint for my July 2020

Comment: I feel bad I had to look this up, because reading is hard :(
tyvm tho!

Comment: The Keyboard Controls section doesn't appear for me.  I've been using Chrome RD for years but just recently copy/paste stopped working.  I had to use @kguie 's answer.

Answer (score 17):

On the right side of Chrome Remote Desktop, the small blue arrow has Keyboard controls and its submenu has the option to enable the clipboard.

Comment: Working like charm.

Comment: I'm not seeing a submenu for clipboard, although I remember one going by before. Here's what I see: https://www.evernote.com/l/AA8NtwISytNBcpOYiv9xNX7bkIDksxnw62E

Comment: Please delete your comment. The link you provided no longer works!

Answer (score 3):

After latest update (Dec 2021) of Chrome Remote Desktop, Ctrl-C Ctrl-V no longer works and Copy/Paste doesn't work on Windows 10. There is no apparent way to activate the clipboard.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Took me a while to check how to copy-paste from **Windows** into a **Mac** via Google Remote Desktop.

- Open the **Session options** via the arrow, select **Configure key mappings** and map:

  | From | To |
  | --- | --- |
  | ControlLeft | MetaLeft |

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Remote Desktop can do it all. It will do the copy/paste keyboard shortcuts via the usual CTRL-C CTRL V.

[image: And will do file upload/download via the links on the left panel:]

Comment: Fine for text.  But file transfer must be done via the upload/download link on the "right-side" remote desktop menu.  And the file go to the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

2023/03/15

if the "begin" is disappeared, go to

```
chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=https%3A%2F%2Fremotedesktop.google.com
```

set clipboard to allow

Comment: THANKS!  NOTE: Do this using the Chrome browser.